# Using an existing AMD js module in a new typescript file (0.9)

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

I am trying to use an existing AMD written in pure javascript with a new TypeScript file using TypeScript v0.9.  I've broken it down to a very simple AMD to demonstrate the issue.

First, my existing AMD (activityProperty.js):

```
define([],
    function () {
        var activityProperty = function (key, value) {
            var self = this;

            self.key = key;
            self.value = value;

            return self;
        };

        return activityProperty;
    });
```

Second, I created activityProperty.d.ts with an interface definiton of the existing AMD:

```
export interface IActivityProperty {
    key: string;
    value: string;
}
```

Finally, I created a brand new TypeScript class (PropertyBag.ts) where I wish to use my old activityProperty AMD:

```
import PropertyModule = require("activityProperty");

class PropertyBag {
    private properties: Array<PropertyModule.IActivityProperty>;

    constructor() {
        this.properties = new Array<PropertyModule.IActivityProperty>();

        //this is where my problem is...
        //this.properties.push(???new activityProperty()???);
    }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use the old AMD definition to create a new instance of the `activityProperty` class.  Am I missing something trivial or obvious?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your declaration only has an interface. Declare it as a class to show it can be newed and/or extended...

```
declare class ActivityProperty {
    constructor(public key: string, public value: string);
}
```

You can decide whether to keep your interface or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Steve.  However, I just used this as a small scale example as we have AMD definitions that are substantially larger  and I'm looking for a way to use them  in this manner without a rewrite.  So imagine the interface isn't even there.  Is there a way to use the class defined in the very first `define` statement from TypeScript?

Comment: OK, this was most of the answer, but I did have to add the new `export = activityProperty;` to get the class to be recognized by the new TypeScript class that consumes it.  Thanks to you and @stephen-chung for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't compile to JavaScript that will work straight with your external AMD module, because your AMD module exports the class itself, not a namespace with an IActivityProperty property pointing to your class.

You need to define your system this way:

activityProperty.d.ts:

```
declare module "activityProperty"
{
    class activityProperty {
        constructor(key: KeyType, value: ValueType);
        key: KeyType;
        value: ValueType;
    }

    export = activityProperty;
}
```

PropertyBag.ts:

```
/// <reference path="activityProperty.d.ts" />
import activityProperty = module("activityProperty");

this.properties = new Array<activityProperty>();
this.properties.push(new activityProperty(key, value));
```

This will compile straight to JavaScript that works with your external AMD modules. However, I think what you really want is:

activityProperty.d.ts:

```
declare module "activityProperty"
{
    class activityProperty<K, T> {
        constructor(key: K, value: T);
        key: K;
        value: T;
    }

    export = activityProperty;
}
```

PropertyBag.ts:

```
/// <reference path="activityProperty.d.ts" />
import activityProperty = module("activityProperty");

var x = new activityProperty("hello", 123);   // Type inferred to be activityProperty<string, number>
```

Comment: While rewriting the AMD in TypeScript in incredibly easy for this example, there are other AMDs that would not be trivial at all.  I'm looking to use the existing JS AMD defintiions with a new TypeScript file.

Comment: In that case, you probably would nullify most of the advantages of TypeScript, which is static typing.  In order to use static typing, you're always going to need a .d.ts definitions file...  Otherwise, a simple "declare var activityProperty;" or of any external root object will let you interoperate with external JavaScript, but without the benefits of type checking.

Comment: Also, notice that you *don't* have to rewrite the AMD in TypeScript.  In your example, activityProperty.js stays as it is. You just need a definitions file matching your js (e.g. activityProperty.d.ts).  By coding it in the format I described, the compiled JavaScript (i.e. propertyBag.js) automatically loads your activityProperty.js when run with your AMD loader.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, between you and Steve Fenton's answers I was able to resolve it and use my old AMDs with new TypeScript classes!